# Angular Reactive Forms - Exclude empty fields on form submit

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to get only fields from the form with values entered by the user. The resulting JSON object from still contains empty quotation marks for empty inputs (see below). Is there a way to exclude empty fields upon form submit? Thank you!

Current:
    `{ "user": "", "directory": "documents", "filename": [ "a", "", "" ] }`

Goal: `{ "directory": "documents", "filename": [ "a" ] }`

Comment: You can have just one level of prop? Or you object can be more complex like: 

```{ prop: { propArr: [] } }```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't assign an empty value to the form controls, then these will automatically be `null`.

Considering this is how you're creating your form:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  userForm = this.fb.group({
    user: [],
    directory: [],
    filename: this.fb.array([])
  });

  addFile() {
    (<FormArray>this.userForm.get('filename')).push(this.fb.control(null));
  }

  get files() {
    return (<FormArray>this.userForm.get('filename')).controls;
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.userForm.value);
  }

}
```

The form value would yield `null` for fields that were not filled. You can then remove them from the `value` like this:

```
onSubmit() {
  let formValue = { ...this.userForm.value };

  for (let prop in formValue) {
    if (!formValue[prop]) {
      delete formValue[prop];
    }

    if (Array.isArray(formValue[prop])) {
      let resultArray = formValue[prop].filter(item => item);
      if (resultArray.length > 0) {
        formValue[prop] = resultArray;
      } else {
        delete formValue[prop];
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(formValue);
}
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-json-placeholder-form?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: Nice solution! I would add a little refactoring that takes into account nested FormArray:

function removeNullValueField(formValue) {
  for (const prop in formValue) {
    if (formValue.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      if (!formValue[prop]) {
        delete formValue[prop];
      }
      if (Array.isArray(formValue[prop]) && formValue[prop].length > 0) {
        formValue[prop].forEach(fsValue => {
          this.removeNullValueField(fsValue);
        });
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: @siddAjmera - That's amazing! - However, is there a way to ensure that it doesn't exclude any properties that have a value set to 0 (number). Using the above currently results in the form ignoring any numerical value of 0